# Simple Playback Requesting Access to Microphone

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, playback

I have a sound clip in my app. Now, iOS is requesting access to the microphone. Is that necessary for a simple playback? Here's the code snippet:

```
func _playSound() {
    do {
        if let fileURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "clip", ofType: "aiff") {
            _clip = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL))
            _clip?.volume = 0.3
        } else {
            print("ERROR: No file with specified name exists in _playSound()")
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("ERROR: AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: _) threw an error in _playSound(); Message: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    _clip?.play()
}
```

Comment: Does that happen for you on device or simulator? If simulator then you might review the issues in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes

Comment: So far, I have only seen it on the simulator and even then it seem intermittent. But I just added the feature last night so have not had much opportunity to interact with it on my device.

I read the release notes. I guess it's close to what I'm seeing. The notes are referring to macOS and to using the microphone which my app is not.